# How do I make graphviz repeat the nodes in the graph to create a tree-like image?

Tags: graph, tree, graphviz, dot

I have the following graph on graphviz:

[image: Original graph with converging paths]

How do I make graphviz repeat the nodes in the graph so I can get a tree-like image like this:

[image: Derived tree with repeated labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can make this modification of the graph within graphviz. You should feed graphviz a different graph, with the structure you desire. That graph can be obtained by a process like the following (pseudocode):

```
function visit(path: a list of nodes):
  let n be the last node on the path
  for every child c of n:
    write (a copy of) c to output
    if c is not in path:
      visit(path + [c])
write root to output
visit([root])
```

Instead of this list `path` you can also mark nodes as `visited` before the recursive call and remove that flag after the call:

```
function visit(n: a node):
  mark n as visited
  for every child c of n:
    write (a copy of) c to output
    if c is not marked as visited:
      visit(c)
  mark n as not visited
write root to output
visit(root)
```

Comment: I think that the pseudocode you wrote will give me the same result as the picture of the graph that I posted. A child "c" can appear multiple times in a tree, and writing that on a dot file will not make a difference.

Comment: @PedroVictorPontesPinheiro, that's why I told you to write a copy, i.e. write the same node multiple times, so that it appears multiple times in the graph. Means you have to use different node identifiers for each copy. I probably shouldn't have put the “copy of” in parentheses.

Comment: Hm, I see. I'll test that, Thanks so much for the help. I was hoping there were a better way by just using some command. But I guess this is the only way.